# How to optimise OR operation using index

Tags: indexing

OR operation will use multi column index

I created one multicolumn index

```sql
Create index name1 tablename(col1, col2);
```

I am try to optimise my query

```sql
Select * from tablename where col1= value1 or col2 = value 2
```

Also we have two different separate index for this two column col1 and col2

Now when I check for execution plan for this, it taking separate index of both column name, not multi column name why